# search through listbox using comma separated values in textbox vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a code to search through the entire listbox items and highlight them whenever user enters text in textbox. I am looping through textbox items which are entered using a 'comma' . But the code fails to add it to selected indices when user types multiple items using comma. It works fine for single items.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then

            ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
            ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Clear()

            If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
                Dim lstOfStrings() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
                For Each s As String In lstOfStrings
                    For index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

                        If s.Trim() <> "" Then

                            Dim item As String = ListBox1.Items(index).ToString()

 If item.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then

                                ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Add(index)

                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Next s
                End
                If True Then

                End If


            End If

            ListBox1.EndUpdate()
```

I think I am missing correct loops or anything else?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing using **TextBox1.Text** instead of your 'For Each' variable **s**

The line

```
If item.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
```

should be changed to

```
If item.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you Listbox has the property SelectionMode changed to Multi instead of the default of "One"